# NoClassDefFoundError while running jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have exported jar file from eclipse. And i am running it from command line. But getting following exception-

```
F:\>java -jar demo1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
Could not find the main class: a.Driver.  Program will exit.
```

MainFest file entries-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: a.Driver
Class-Path: F:\Selenium Jars\testng-6.0.jar
```

is there anything i am missing

Comment: Why does the manifest have an absolute path reference?  What is the contents of `demo1.jar?

Comment: In class-path i have given reference to testng jar as i am using selenium. I will change it later by kiping that jar in lib folder.

Jar contents-Package containing class files,META-INF folder,.classpath file,.project file,testng.xml    . my package contains main class which calls this testng.xml

Comment: Unzip the Jar file and check that `a/Driver.class` actually exists

Comment: Did you use the eclipse export runnable JAR? Did you change any settings? Which required library option did you select?

Comment: I haven't made runnable jar. It is causing problem due to testng.jar. If i remove testng.jar from project main class is running properly from cmd

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file is telling the java command that the main method is in a java class named `a.Driver`.  Java will therefore try to load that class from your jar, from entry `a/Driver.class` relative to the root of your jar, and then to invoke its method `static void main(String[])`.  Error thrown indicates that Java does not find that file in the jar.